# Webview e CSS como verificar o que é compatível?

Tags: android, css, ios, webview

Ando a experimentar fazer uma aplicação com **Webview** para **android e iOS** (aplicações diferentes para cada sistema), e gostava de saber como a janela de acesso à Internet lê **CSS** e verifica a sua compatibilidade. Ou seja qual o **"Browser Support"** que tenho que verificar para saber que as minhas opções de CSS são aceites.

Assumo que a Webview em **android** seja o equivalente a usar um browser **Chrome** e por isso suporte o mesmo CSS, e que **iOS** seja o equivalente a um browser **Safari** e que suporte o respetivo CSS. Isto é correcto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre o Chrome e o Android Browser eu não consigo te afirmar plenamente, mas se existem um [Chrome específico para Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=pt_BR), muito possivelmente é pq ele é diferente do Browser nativo Android.

Sobre o Safari sim eu posso afirmar que existem diferenças, e a maior parte delas envolve performance e não somente suporte ao CSS e vendor prefix.

O Safari Mobile é otimizado para funcionar em dispositivos de poucos recursos de hardware, ou seja, é otimizado para dispositivos que não têm o mesmo poder de processamento de um maquina desktop.

Como a Apple quer otimizar a UX e a performance de iPhone ela limita algumas propriedade que consomem muitos recursos da maquina. Um exemplo "clássico" disso é que o Safari Mobile não permitir a propriedade `background-attachment: fixed;`, pois ela é muito custosa para o navegador e prejudica o desempenho do celular. Vc pode ler mais aqui [Problema de background com Iphone 6, 7 e 8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306415/problema-de-background-com-iphone-6-7-e-8/306421#306421)

Acredito que o Browser Android tb tenha algumas dessas artimanhas, já o Chrome Android acredito ser uma reprodução mais fiel do que é o Chrome Desktop, além de ter funções mais inerentes ao ambiente mobile como navegação por voz, salvar para ver offline e alguns gerenciadores de compactação e cacheamento de dados. Inclusive acredito que o próprio fabricando como Asus, Samsung, etc, podem limitar ou não recursos do Browser nativo, o próprio https://caniuse.com/ faz menção a isso na descrição do Browser quando descreve alguma propriedade CSS

> Support listed is for the Android core; it should be noted that many hardware vendors (Samsung, HTC, etc.) use altered version of their default browser

Traduzindo: *"O suporte listado é para o núcleo do Android; Deve-se notar que muitos fornecedores de hardware (Samsung, HTC, etc.) usam versões alteradas de seu navegador padrão"*

Comment: Então como iOS webview posso usar o que eles não permitem no browser mobile? Como o exemplo do ``background-attachment: fixed;````?

Comment: @Pbras pode pode, mas não vai funcionar pq o Browser Safari iOS não vai reconhecer a propriedade. Esse é apenas um exemplo que eu sei que não funciona, mas não sei sei existem outros propriedades tipo essa documentadas, ou se a Apple fala abertamente sobre isso.... Até pq tanto Apple quanto Google são bem obscuras quanto a limitar recursos do usuário para forçar algum comportamento como a migração e plataforma ou a compra de um novo dispositivo