# Como fixar um conteúdo ou um fundo em uma div

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de fazer com essa `div` **rolasse** junto com a página mas o seu conteúdo ou o conteúdo de um before que seria no caso a imagem(se fosse o caso), ficasse **fixado** de forma que desse a aparência de o conteúdo (ou fundo) sumisse ao rolar a página.

De fato, como eu fiz o fundo ficou fixo mas ele não foi sumindo de  acordo com que eu *rolasse a página*. A ideia é fazer tipo um `overflow: hidden`.

```css
#teste {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#teste:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/%24700%2C000_Home.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id=teste></div>

eu <br />
eu <br />
eu <br />
eu <br />
eu <br />
eu <br />
eu <br />
eu <br />
eu <br />
eu <br />
eu <br />
eu <br />
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas é isso que quer? https://repl.it/@Costamilam/HurtfulHilariousKeygens

Comment: Não! O que eu quero fazer é o que acontece no banner que está no topo desse site: https://www.banesecard.com.br/Home/

Comment: Mas teria como você alterar esse teu exemplo para ficar apenas a div.imagem e um bloco de eu <br /> como na pergunta para fazer om que o efeito que ocorre na div.imagem continue ocorrendo? Porém, ao invés de content do before ter 'Imegem', gostaria que existisse mesmo uma imagem, pode ser do google, que tivesse as dimensoes da div.

Comment: Não entendi bem o que quer, parece que tu já tem o que deseja, só arrumar o `z-index` como o hugocsl respondeu. Você pode inspecionar elemento e ver como foi feito no site para tirar alguma dúvida

Comment: Carlos Editei completamente a resposta, acho que agora está mais de acordo com o efeito que vc queria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa técnica na verdade não é com um elemento com `position:fixed`, mas sim um elemento com `background-attachment: fixed`. Dessa forma o elemento rola com a tela, mas o `background` dele não, ai da esse efeito meio que de `parallax`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: red;
}

.fixo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
 background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/%24700%2C000_Home.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center center;

}
.con {
/* essa altura é só para vc ver melhor o exemplo, mas vc não precisa definir uma altura aqui*/
    height: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="fixo">
    conteúdo qq
</div>
<div class="con">
    resto do content
</div>
```

**OBS:** A única ressalva que fica é sobre o `background-attachment: fixed` nos iOS dos iPhones mais antigos como vc pode ver aqui [Problema de background com Iphone 6, 7 e 8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306415/problema-de-background-com-iphone-6-7-e-8/306421#306421)

Comment: Oi Hugo, ainda não é isso! O que eu quero fazer é o que acontece no banner que está no topo desse site: https://www.banesecard.com.br/Home/

Comment: @CarlosRocha agora entendi melhor, fiz uma edição por completo da resposta, inclusive a técnica é outra, diferente do que a gente pensou inicialmente... ;)

Comment: Hum, entendi. Mas a imagem precisa ser obrigatoriamente do tamanho da div Como faz?

Comment: @CarlosRocha não jovem, aqui `.fixo { ...  height: 100px;` vc pode coloca a altura que achar melhor, inclusive em pixels, na outra div eu coloquei uma altura só para ter scroll na página e vc poder ver e testar o efeito. https://imgur.com/IALMY03 com 100px de altura em .fixo ficara assim

Comment: hum. Mas esse height: 100px é o tamanho da div. O que eu preciso é que a imagem tenha o tamanho da div. Eu coloquei background-size: cover; e nãp funcionou. Será que não precisa usar um :before?

Comment: Carlos pra que ::before se a imagem é o background da div principal? Vc está complicando as coisas sem motivo...

Comment: devo estar sim. Mas aqui para mim, a imagem de fundo está  muito maior que a div. E o objetivo é que a imagem permaneça da altura do div.

Comment: @CarlosRocha eu **editei** a resposta e coloquei um `background-position: center center;` para centralizar a imagem no tamanho da div, vc pode alterar para tipo `top left` se quiser para ver se fica mais do seu agrado... Tb mudei a altura para vc ver que a imagem respeita sim o tamanho da div, pois ela é o background da própria div e não tem como ser maior que ela....

Comment: Agora só mais essa dúvda: Sabendo que a altura da imagem será sempre 32% da largura e sabendo que a largura da imagem será será sempre a largura de uma div container.
Como eu calculo a altura dessa div containner para que ela nunca empurre as divs de baixo? 
Eu tentei height: calc (100vw * 0.3251622); mas não funcionou –

Comment: @CarlosRocha na boa jovem, ai já é outra pergunta... se tu tiver duvida com outra coisa abre outra Pergunta, coloca o seu problema, imagem de como esta ai e como vc precisa que fique etc, ai eu ou outro alguém pode te ajudar com esse problema. Sobre o efeito que vc queria acho que vc já resolveu

Comment: de acordo. Obrigado. Vou postar outra!